# Border for an Image view in Android?

Tags: android, border, imageview

How can I set a border for an `ImageView` and change its color in Android?

Comment: I have a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20656371/1251276) for changing a ImageView's color, hope can help.

Answer (score 624, accepted):

I set the below xml to the background of the Image View as Drawable. It works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

And then add `android:background="@drawable/yourXmlFileName"` to your `ImageView`

Comment: And then add `android:background="@drawable/yourXmlFileName"` to `ImageView`

Comment: My layout in the activity is like this
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/picture" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" />
 </LinearLayout>
The border fills the whole background where ever the picture doesn't cover, which is white is this case. Is there a way to wrap the imageView with a 1 dp border but still using this method?

Comment: I can not get you properly. If you do not want to show the white background then change the `<solid>` color to transparent or something whatever you want.

Comment: The border works both both the left and right, but for top and bottom it fills the parent to the top.

Comment: do you mean that you are not getting the border on top and bottom? is it?

Comment: first we need to know which place you border covers. So please change you `<stroke>` color to red(#FF0000). then you will get some idea.

Comment: Oh good, that's what I want too. Remember to set padding for your ImageView.

Comment: thank you so much! it worked for me! i only added the padding, because my imageview didn't have top and bottom lines.. the padding solved it. thanks!!

Comment: I think it's more practical to simply use a red (#ffff0000) stroke.

Comment: can we change border in java file

Comment: @Maurice You can set cropToPadding to true.

Comment: For 'And then add `android:background="@drawable/yourXmlFileName"` to ImageView.', NOTE: minus ".xml" there. And, don't use '-' in the filename (in general, with resources). (Took me a few recompilations to find out.)

Comment: For transparent images this gives a background rather than a border.

Comment: Took me some time to figure this out, but in code: setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_xml_here));

Comment: @praveen how can change the border color each time should i have to change in stroke attribute of xml?

Comment: dont forget set cropToPadding="true"

Comment: On the other answer you comment that it draws a black background, which is not intended. Your answer draws a white background, which is also not intended. You should change `#FFFFFF` to `@android:color/transparent` or `#00000000`.

Comment: Add a padding to see the efect¡

Answer (score 175):

Following is the code that i used to have black border. Note that i have not used extra xml file for border.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/red_minus_icon"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="1dp"/>
```

Comment: yeah.. it looks like a border. But when you use a drawable image with tranparent background, then it will not show your image with border properly. it shows black color whereever you have the transparent. So your answer is not a best approach.

Comment: Yeah! but you have a border without creating another xml file.

Comment: This doesn't work when you resize the image using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

Comment: this is bad because it creates unnecessary overdraw

Comment: @Silox for `scaleType="centerCrop"`, make sure to also add `cropToPadding="true"`

Comment: I've also use `scaleType="centerCrop"` with `cropToPadding="true"` but in rare case still not showing rounded corner

Comment: +1 as for this approach you can also draw a border around an image without straight edges. just set the same image as background. @Praveen: Have you tried to set android:backgroundTint? Setting this you can even use transparent background images.

Answer (score 36):

`ImageView` in xml file

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"

            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:background="@drawable/border_image"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

save below code with the name of `border_image.xml` and it should be in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff" />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0.7dp"
        android:color="#b4b4b4" />
</shape>
```

if you want to give rounded corner to the border of image then you may change a line in border.xml file

```
<corners android:radius="4dp" />
```

Comment: just a note on this, if the image is set dynamically then the border needs to be set again in code other wise the image is over the border.

Comment: I didn't see any weirdness when I used `ImageView.setImageBitmap(photoBmp)'

Answer (score 25):

This is an old post I know, but I thought this might possibly help someone out there.

If you want to simulate a translucent border that doesn't overlap the shape's "solid" color, then use this in your xml. Note that I don't use the "stroke" tag here at all as it seems to always overlap the actual drawn shape.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#55111111" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />

            <solid android:color="#ff252525" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I like this too but if you make the outside edges too small, the corners are blank. It works well with anything 2dp and above.

Comment: The benefit of this method is that it allows for rounded corners. If you don't want the border from the previous answer to overlap, add padding to the ImageView tag. The drawback to this method is that the border will bleed into the image area if using a translucent background. So I choose the previous method because I like the translucent background better than the rounded corners.

Answer (score 6):

### Create Border

Create an xml file (e.g. "frame_image_view.xml") with the following content in your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/borderThickness"
        android:color="@color/borderColor" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="@dimen/borderThickness"
        android:left="@dimen/borderThickness"
        android:right="@dimen/borderThickness"
        android:top="@dimen/borderThickness" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" /> <!-- remove line to get sharp corners -->
</shape>
```

Replace `@dimen/borderThickness` and `@color/borderColor` with whatever you want or add corresponding dimen / color.

Add the Drawable as background to your ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_image_view"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

You have to use `android:cropToPadding="true"`, otherwise the defined padding has no effect. Alternatively use `android:padding="@dimen/borderThickness"` in your ImageView to achieve the same.
If the border frames the parent instead of your ImageView, try to use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

### Change Color of Border

The easiest way to change your border color in code is using the tintBackgound attribute.

```
ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
img.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED); // changes border color to red
```

or

```
ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
img.setBackgroundTintList(getColorStateList(R.color.newColor));
```

Don't forget to define your `newColor`.

Comment: the stroke looks good - however, there's a transparent gap (top and bottom) between the frame and the image.

Answer (score 6):

With Material design and the new [ShapeableImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView) widget, you can easily create an image that has a border using the `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth` attributes. This is simple and doesn't involve creating any extra XML file.

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/black"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sample_image" />
```

The above code creates a black border with a width of 2dp.

In cases where you might want to add a stroke to rounded image, you can use the `shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute. This allows you to draw the bitmap with the provided shape (round in this case). Check the below code for more details:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circleImageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sample_image"
        app:strokeColor="@color/black"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

Add the below code to your `styles.xml` file:

```
<!-- Circle Shape -->
<style name="circleImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Make sure your app extends the material design theme in order to use the `ShapeableImageView`.

Comment: android:padding="2dp" is essential to avoid cutting off the stroke

Answer (score 4):

Add a background Drawable like res/drawables/background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

Update the ImageView background in res/layout/foo.xml:

```
...
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="1dp"
  android:background="@drawable/background"
  android:src="@drawable/bar" />
...
```

Exclude the ImageView padding if you want the src to draw over the background.

Answer (score 3):

This has been used above but not mentioned exclusively.

```
setCropToPadding(boolean);
```

If *true*, the image will be cropped to fit within its padding.

This will make the `ImageView` source to fit within the padding's added to its background.

Via XML it can be done as below-

```
android:cropToPadding="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

you must create a background.xml in res/drawable this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners android:radius="6dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="6dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />
<padding
    android:bottom="6dp"
    android:left="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:top="6dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are searching custom border and shape of ImageView. You can use [android-shape-imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)

[image]

Just add `compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'` to your `build.gradle`.

And use in your layout.

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.BubbleImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/neo"
    app:siArrowPosition="right"
    app:siSquare="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is my simplest solution to this lengthy trouble.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="112dp"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" <!-- May vary according to your needs -->
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" <!-- May vary according to your needs -->
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <!-- following imageView acts as the boarder which sitting in the background of our main container ImageView -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="#000"/>
    <!-- following imageView holds the image as the container to our image -->
    <!-- layout_margin defines the width of our boarder, here it's 1dp -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/itemImageThumbnailImgVw"
        android:src="@drawable/banana"
        android:background="#FFF"/> </FrameLayout>
```

In the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931583/1752988) I've explained it well enough, please have a look at that too!

I hope this will be helpful to someone else out there!

Answer (score 1):

In the same xml I have used next:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff" <!-- border color -->
        android:padding="3dp"> <!-- border width -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of adding the background colour that you want as the colour of your border, then
[image]

change the cropToPadding to true and after that add padding.

Then you will have your border for your imageView.

Answer (score 1):

I almost gave up about this.

This is my condition using glide to load image, see [detailed glide issue here about rounded corner transformations](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3189#issuecomment-576369171) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49778043/3763032)

I've also the same attributes for my `ImageView`, for everyone answer [here 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3264140/3763032), [here 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24691841/3763032) & [here 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404153/3763032)

```
android:cropToPadding="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"`
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/path_to_rounded_drawable"
```

But still no success.

After researching for awhile, using a `foreground` attributes from [this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038312/3763032) give a result `android:foreground="@drawable/all_round_border_white"`

unfortunately it giving me the "not nice" border corner like below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use 9 patch in Android Studio to make borders!

I was looking for a solution but I did not find any so I skipped that part.

Then I went to the Google images of Firebase assets and I accidentally discovered that they use 9patch.

[image: 9patch in action]

Here's the link: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

You just need to drag where the edges are.

It's just like border edge in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code in your **ImageView**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/white"/>

    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it so much easier to do this:

1) Edit the frame to have the content inside (with 9patch tool).

2) Place the `ImageView` inside a `Linearlayout`, and set the frame background or colour you want as the background of the `Linearlayout`. As you set the frame to have the content inside itself, your `ImageView` will be inside the frame (right where you set the content with the 9patch tool).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Indented border]

Add the following code to a shape:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:endColor="#FF444444"
    android:centerColor="#FFAAAAAA"
    android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>
```

ét voila, you've got a (more or less) indented border, with the light source set to left-top. Fiddle with the size of the bitmap (in relation to the size of the imageview, I used a 200dp x 200dp imageview and a bitmap of 196dp x 196dp in the example, with a radius of 14dp for the corners) and the padding to get the best result. Switch end and startcolor for a bevelled effect.

Here's the full code of the shape you see in the image (save it in res/drawable, e.g. border_shape.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:endColor="#FF444444"
        android:centerColor="#FFAAAAAA"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <padding
        android:top="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

And call it in your imageview like this:

```
android:scaleType="center"    
android:background="@drawable/border_shape"
android:cropToPadding="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

And here is the code for the bitmap with rounded corners:

```
Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float radius) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    PorterDuffXfermode pdmode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(0xff424242);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, radius, radius, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(pdmode);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return bm;
}
```