# How To Display Border To Imageview?

Tags: android, image, imageview, border, android-imageview

Friends How To Display Border To Imageview ?

I Want To Result Like Mobile gallery all image display with border.

plz give me ans thanks for advance....

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can create a resource (layer drawable xml) for your `ImageView`'s "border" (actually background), and declare in your `theme` that the `ImageView`'s background resource is the drawable xml.

If you need this "border" to be changed based on the `ImageView`'s state (`focused`, `selected`, etc.), then you should create more layer drawables, and put them together into a selector xml (state drawable). 
Then in your theme you should set the `ImageView`'s background to be this `selector.xml`.

**Update**
Below is a sample of how to specify a simple border to your images, that will result in

[image: efteling with border]

You have to

1. create a new layer drawable file (`image_border.xml`),
2. modify/create your `styles.xml` file
3. modify/create your `colors.xml` file
4. modify your layout xml file (or your code) to apply the style to the `ImageView`.

**res/drawable/image_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="90" 
                android:startColor="@color/image_border_start" 
                android:centerColor="@color/image_border_center"
                android:endColor="@color/image_border_end" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp" android:left="2dp" 
        android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/default_back_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**res/values/styles.xml**
Add the following lines:

```
<style name="myImageView">
    <!-- 3dp so the background border to be visible -->
    <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/image_border</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
</style>
```

**res/values/colors.xml**
Add the following lines:

```
<color name="image_border_start">#40990000</color>
<color name="image_border_end">#FF660000</color>
<color name="image_border_center">#FFFF3333</color>
```

And finally specify the style of your `ImageView` in your **layout xml**:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/my_image" 
    android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/efteling"
    style="@style/myImageView" />
```

Comment: this would cover up the image view if border gets thicker. is there a way to not cover it?

Answer (score 9):

You can use this XML file as a drawable instead of multiple files, but this
file is placed in drawable folder. In ImageView use this XML file as a
background drawable, like: `android:background="@drawable/following code file
name"`.

I hope this is helpful for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above solutions but they didn't work for me!
So I figured out a simple solution to this! :-)

I remember that I read about FrameLayout of Android in the following [article](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/) saying that it helps us to stack up our UI elements on top of each other in the same order we add them up.

**Solution:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="112dp"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" <!-- May vary according to your needs -->
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" <!-- May vary according to your needs -->
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <!-- following imageView acts as the boarder which sitting in the background of our main container ImageView -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="#000"/>
    <!-- following imageView holds the image as the container to our image -->
    <!-- layout_margin defines the width of our boarder, here it's 1dp -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/itemImageThumbnailImgVw"
        android:src="@drawable/banana"
        android:background="#FFF"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Preview:**

And that's it. You will get the following like imageView!

[image: preview of the ImageView with boarder]

**Pros and Cons:**

I think this is pretty easy solution to be used in anywhere else and it's all the things you do sits in one single place so easier to modify it. However I don't like to having to add two ImageViews.