# How to draw a layout of this type in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to provide a background drawable, similar to the one shown in the figure, to a layout. How can i do it using a drawable xml? Please suggest a suitable approach to go about this.

[image: rectangleCutFromBottom]

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841128/how-to-display-border-to-imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with single xml drawable but probably you can club two to create this effect. I would do it this way

1. Create a drawable of square type with black borders
2. Create a clip drawable and clip the bottom of sqaure drawable.

Reference here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip

You can use the android:gravity="top" and then programmatically set the level to reveal 90% (or more) of the image

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) imageview.getDrawable();
drawable.setLevel(drawable.getLevel() + 9500);
```

Comment: Thanks rahul for a quick reply. I am using the approach you suggested. I tried using android:gravity=["top" | "right" | "left" ] as given in the clip drawable docs. But this syntax is giving me error in my xml file. However, when i use a single attribute android:gravity="top" it works fine, and only the top line is visible. Please help me with this?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you would need to set the level programmatically. I wonder why this couldn't be another property in the xml file :-?

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4+ years after the fact but for anyone else wanting to achieve the same result, there's a very simple way to achieve this by creating a `layer-list` xml `drawable`.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:top="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp" />
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Save this to your project's `drawable` folder and reference it like any other drawable (`android:src` / `android:background`, or programatically)