# Styled gridview with border android

Tags: android, gridview, styles

Im creating a gallery type app. I have the basics up and running where all the pictures is loaded from the phone and gets displayed in a gridview. I want each images in the gridview to have a border, probably a white so that they stand out a bit from the black background. I want to achieve something like this gridview that new Instagram uses, but maybe not so advanced with shadows around them. I have searched the net but I have not found anything.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Display Border To Imageview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841128/how-to-display-border-to-imageview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an xml file named stroke.xml in drawable folder,

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

And set the background of your ImageView which you use in your GridView, to that xml file.

**EDIT**: If you want to see the orange or blue color when you click the GridView item, you would have to specify the properties of the ImageView as follows..

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivHighThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:background="@drawable/stroke" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin="10dip" />
```

Here please take notes of the properties

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_margin="10dip"
```

That is what makes your item feel like its being clicked and its highlighted.

Also include this xml part in stroke.xml file

```
<padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
```

For better looking results...

Comment: Wonderful, just what I needed. Thanks a a lot!! Simple and easy.

Comment: Works perfect, but this way I loose the selected style when its selected. How do I make it appear selected when I select it? Maybe just change the border color or something like that. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean you don't see the orange or blue highlight color when you select the item?

Comment: Yes. I have been trying to solve that but I have not found a solution yet.