# Change the Style of an Image View on Pressed State in Android

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-styles

I have an ImageView in my application. When user Clicks the imageView I am supposed to show a border around the ImageView. This Border style I have it as a style called "myStyle" in my styles.xml.

I need to show this style only when the user clicks the image view. How can I do this?

Comment: Go to this: [how-to-display-border-to-imageview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841128/how-to-display-border-to-imageview)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime/6390025#6390025

Comment: you need `selector` xml and set that as your background of your button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i will advice you to get the border style info into an xml file and save it at the drawable folder - let's call it border_pressed.xml.

And then at the drawable folder create a file called, let's say, imagview_state.xml and put in it the next code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/border_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>

</selector>
```

and at the layout file - where the ImageView is- set it's background like that -

```
android:background="@drawable/imagview_state"
```