# Android how to make border with Imageview

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have been searching for similar problems/situations but to no anvil, I find myself looking for your help.

I have a good general understanding of Androids interface system through XML. I want to set a border on all sides, left, right, bottom and top of an image-view.

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:background="#555555">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_de_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0.1dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous_item" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I understand that the margin property separates views by the defined unit. In this case I have it set to 0.1dp of the its parent view which has a background color of #555555. The left, top, and right borders are present, but the bottom border line is not...

Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong or my misunderstanding?

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in xml file and add this xml file as your imageview background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#222222" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" /></shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this drawable as your image view background.

image_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="@color/color_transparent" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#ff6600" />

<corners android:radius="2dp" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

above all ans may helps you lot but there is a tool for this use that in future

> http://angrytools.com/android/button/

and Ans to your question create `image_border.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid
  android:color="#D4D4D4"/>
<size
  android:width="202dp"
  android:height="60dp"/>
<stroke
  android:width="4dp"
  android:color="#8E939C"/>
</shape>
```

and apply to your `ImageView` as background

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in XML in your drawable folder and name it myImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

And specify the drawable of your ImageView in your layout xml:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/my_image" 
    android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/myImageView"
     />
```

For more you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841128/how-to-display-border-to-imageview)