# Android Layout Questions

Tags: java, android, view, android-layout, android-view

I tried to create an edittext textbox that will compute the width and height automatically by using the WRAP_CONTENT way. However, at some point of time I will need the actual height of the edit text, but I tried using layout params and getWidth(), getHeight(), I am not being returned with the values I will require.

Anyone have got any idea how can I go about this?

Comment: Why do you need the actual height? Tell us more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Cristian I am trying to create a simple border outside the edittext when I click a specific button, maybe instead you can tell me what would be a better way of doing that?

Comment: What about changing the background of the `EditText`? That way android will take care of apply the border correctly. (yes, background; the background of an EditText contains also the drawing information of its border)

Comment: @Cristian the border will be just a simple black line at each side of the edittext, but by applying the background, it will turn my whole edittext black?

Comment: It will work fine just like you want if you create the appropriate nine-patch image.

Comment: @Cristian i found another solution at [Question: Border texture for a View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android) which can be a feasible solution i need, but it seems that I have problems inflating it, [Question: Problems with drawing a border in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151723/problems-with-drawing-a-border-in-android) maybe you can help me with this instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `view.layout()` and then `view.measure()` in order for those values to be available to you prior to actual "layout" and display on the screen.

You need to be careful with wrap_content, though, because if your content is not already present in the view, it will not return the values you're looking for.

Hope this helps.