# Problems with drawing a border in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve a border to wrap my edittext like this given in the answer of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074546/border-texture-for-a-view).

However, when I tried inflating it to try out how it works, I get an error

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class shape
```

Why is this so?

EDIT

I pasted this in an XML file `(edittext.xml)`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<shape 
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#FAFAD2" />           
     <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="#000000"
        android:dashWidth="7sp" android:dashGap="5sp" />
</shape>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
 public class EditBox extends View {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private FrameLayout viewLayout;

    public EditBox(Context context) {
        super(context);

        try {
           layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           viewLayout = (FrameLayout) layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.edittext, null);

     } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public View getView() {
        return viewLayout;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You don't inflate shapes. Show your code please.

Comment: i have added some code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

the shape should define in xml in drawable folder