# ActionBarSherlock - actionbar custom background with divider

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm implementing [ActionBarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and I want to change the actionbar background.

I override the properties but the blue divider dissapear. How can I use custom background with the blue divider?

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff3e3f3d</item>
    <item name="background">#ff3e3f3d</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 76):

For anyone who (like me) doesn't enjoy playing around with 9-patch images, you can get the divider at the bottom of the action bar using an xml drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Bottom Line -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/action_bar_line_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Color of your action bar -->
    <item android:bottom="2dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/action_bar_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Save this as drawable/action_bar_background.xml, Then apply it in your theme:

```
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Been searching a week for something like this, this is really good!

Comment: How to apply this to Theme.Sherlock.Light?

Comment: how about the menuItem's divider?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623805/actionbarsherlock-stacked-action-bar-styling-issue

Comment: You my friend, are awesome.

Comment: Also using layer-list's, this blog shows how an even more extravagant ActionBar tutorial: http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/make-your-action-bar-beautiful/

Answer (score 17):

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

This project can be used to generate ActionBar style you need.

Comment: Thanks so much for this it's is EXACTLY what I've been looking for, makes theming a hell of a lot easier!

Comment: Is there any tutorial of how to use?? I have no idea where to copy these images and set them.

Answer (score 7):

The blue divider is the background by default. It's a 9-patch drawable which will ensure the line always appears at the bottom of the action bar regardless of its height.

For your situation I would copy the default background `.png`s from Android and then modify them so that the expandable section of the 9-patch is your target background color. This will fill the action bar with your desired color while maintaining the blue border at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to copy the default background and modify them.

Answer (score 3):

Just an update on the answer provided by DanielGrech. It's also possible to use your own custom graphic at the bottom of the actionbar. Like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Bottom Line with custom graphic instead of a solid color-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bar">
          <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>

    <!-- Color of your action bar -->
    <item android:bottom="2dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/action_bar_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```