# How to turn off blue line under ActionBar (ActionBarSherlock)?

Tags: android, styles, themes, actionbarsherlock

I use ActionBarSherlock with theme **Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow** (for using on pre Honeycomb devices) and I need turn off blue line under my ActionBar....is it possible?

**SOLUTION**:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364045/actionbarsherlock-actionbar-custom-background-with-divider?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can remove the bar but you could change the colour of the bar to match that of the background colour?

If you want to try it try this:

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/your_theme_name</item>
<item name="background">@drawable/your_theme_name</item>
```

Comment: west44 Please accept if this is right as I answered first (will be my first correct answer). Hope this is the answer you've been looking for :)

Comment: I create styles.xml in folder res/values and I create new style which has parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow" (my old Theme) and i use your two lines (but with @android:color/transparent becouase I don't know what do you mean with @drawable/your_theme_name) and finally turn on this new style in AndroidManifest.xml. Unfortunately my ActionBar has still blue line...

Comment: by @drawable I meant a folder named "drawable" with your theme inside it. As you have called yours styles.xml you will need to use:
<item name="android:background">@styles/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow</item>
<item name="background">@styles/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow</item>

Comment: I found better solution [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364045/actionbarsherlock-actionbar-custom-background-with-divider?rq=1) but thank you :)

Comment: just checked you solution pretty nice example there cheers for posting it, and thats cool man :)

Answer (score 14):

Another way to solve the problem:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Only solves the problem locally though.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `only solves it locally`, but I can confirm that it does remove the blue line under the action bar

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I think by `only solves it locally` he meant it only  works on the activity that you do `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(null)`. If you were to create a new activity, you'd see the blue line again

Answer (score 4):

That blue line under the ActionBar is part of the background image (which is a 9 patch). Change the background image, or set it to a solid color, and the blue bar will go away.