# How to change the color of a specific component of the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to change the color of a specific part of the action bar; since I really don't know how to call it I will post an image:

[image]

You see the blue line? Well I would like to make it of another color; what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: see the following link to do that:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524867/how-to-turn-off-blue-line-under-actionbar-actionbarsherlock
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736300/android-change-color-of-line-below-actionbar

Comment: You will have to build a custom Actionbar. Take a look here. This is really detailed.  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
 ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
 bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

I commented useful link to do what you want with action bar