# How to style SherlockActionBar menuitem divider

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem, divider

How can I change the color of divider in menuitem (`SherlockActionBar`)?

---

**For better illustration:**

[image]

Comment: refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11006931/2345913)

Comment: Hello Roy,check this link

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364045/actionbarsherlock-actionbar-custom-background-with-divider

Comment: you can make a custom layout then load it from there.

Comment: @CRUSADER thanks, I'm styling the menuitem's divider. does it works d same?