# Android create border drawable programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would create a drawable as background of my list item. I'm trying to draw something like this in xml:

```
------------
|
|
|
|         _|
```

So i need to draw the borders to two sides, top and left, and a "L" in the bottom right corner. I have no problems creating the top and left border but i can't imagine how to create the L in the bottom right corner. PS: the dimension of the L should be fixed and indipendent from the dimensions of the drawable.
Thanks

Comment: It might help if you post some of the code you're using to draw the top and left sides.

Comment: i use almost the same code of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10150908/1665361 . Another problem is to have the central background trasnparent end not white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it create a 9-patch png and then set it as background. i can also change the border color programmatically using a color filter over the drawable