# TableLayout and borders in XML

Tags: android

how do I create a table with TableLayout in XML, and have both the dark borders and the transparent background? Is there a method? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a TableLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- 2 columns -->
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Column 1" />
</TableRow>
```

Dark borders are achieved by making a shape, see this for an example: [Create borders on a android view in drawable xml, on 3 sides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150092/create-borders-on-a-android-view-in-drawable-xml-on-3-sides)

I'm not sure what you mean by a transparent background. Is it a black or white background, or one where you can see the home launcher view?

Comment: I would like to see transparency as a percentage of the background of my app

Comment: What would be behind the app so that it could be transparent?

Comment: I want the background of the LinearLayout is visible in the percentage even having in front of TableLayout

Comment: So you want the LinearLayout to be visible behind the TableLayout?

Comment: Yes, but I want to see also the borders of TableLayout

Comment: That seems like there would be a lot of overlap, it seems confusing.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have two layouts overlapping. You can have them transparent so that you can see the homescreen, though.