# Align 2 images so the first one serves as a border for the second one

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to find out a way to align 2 images. The first image the border image (like a polaroid) and the second a picture. The picture should start in the corner of the border (around 20dp from left and top of the real border image) but that distance varies on what screen you have...

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/border" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I get now:

[image]

The hardest thing is that the image shouldn't pop out the border image and the background behind the whole view (border + image) is variable!

Comment: Maybe you can use the answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android

Comment: No, I need the image as border...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make your border image a 9-patch:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Wouldn't my paperclip being stretched out then?

Comment: I think it could be take out of the border, placed top-left and stacked on top?

Comment: @Ferdau: No, you can easily create a 9-patch image that includes the paperclip in a non-stretchable area. Personally I would try this approach first, before going into the direction of stacking multiple views on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the "border" image as the background drawable of the layout and then position your image on that layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/polaroid_background"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I haven't tested this just now, but it's approximately what you would do.

Comment: Well that wouldn't work for all screen sizes... Since the padding of 20dp will sometimes be to big...

Comment: @Ferdau: 20dp will be scaled up/down based on pixel density, but you would have the same problem with any other way. You need to determine how many pixels you need your border to be.

Comment: @Ferdau I think you don't fully understand how "dp" units work.  Try my code and see what you get.

Comment: I understand, already tried it, just wanted to ask if there wasn't a better solution because doing it that way I don't always get the result I wanted...

Comment: @Ferdau In that case, you may be better off explaining the result you want and the result you get - maybe then we'd be able to help you better.  I have used the approach I described myself - and it looked fine on devices from ldpi to xhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with a similar issue, back_img, img, text. I could deal with it in a really crappy way through styles (for every different screen size), but is the only thing i found that worked...

I set a LinearLayout and put the 3 imgs inside another LinearLayout

```
LinearLayoutLine  //wrap content\\
   LinearLayoutImg1 //wrap content + marginRight\\
      Img11
      Img12
      Text13
   /LinearLayoutImg1

   LinearLayoutImg2
      Img21
      Img22
      Text23
   /LinearLayoutImg2
/LinearLayoutLine
```

In the Styles, something like this:

```
    <style name="img1">
        <item name="android:layout_width">85dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">85dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
    </style>

    <!--  imatge del tema -->
    <style name="img2">
        <item name="android:layout_width">82.6dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">82.6dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">-87dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:layout_width">66dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:lines">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">-25.3dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">-75dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10.5sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blanc</item>
    </style>
```

So, you set Img1 size with a little margin (i found out that sometimes you need that margin in Imgs), and the second one with negative IMG1 width+rightMargin and in case of need, the text.

Comment: Well my image should be filling the screen... So a hardcoded width isn't an option... Thanks for the post though!

Comment: You didn't have the image then :P What about.. creating 2 more images with the frame width/height (depending if they're top/left), setting them as invisible and putting your new image rightTo and Under those images? If they've the same size of your frame, it should do the trick..

Comment: Sorry i didn't explained well enought (or i missunderstood you). You can create 2 extra images, one for top-left corner and another under-top-left corner (without the paperclip, only with needed frame width), then you set them invisible (not gone). And put your photo next those 2 elements. So you'll have it well placed and papercliped