# android add semi-transparent different color border and shadow effect to image

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview

The effect is looks like this:
[image: border and shadow]

please note:

1.The border's color vary from the original image, you can see the Gmail icon border border is  black and the other icon is white. The border's color is from the original image.

2.The image have shadow

And how to implement the clicked effect ?

[image: clicked effect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using setOnClickListner use setOnTouchListener to gain the desired effect

> ((Button)findViewById(R.id.testBth)).setOnTouchListener(new
>   OnTouchListener() {
>
> ```
>       @Override
>         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>           switch (event.getAction()) {
>           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
>               Button view = (Button) v;
>               view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
>               v.invalidate();
>               break;
>           }
>           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>               // Your action here on button click
>           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
>               Button view = (Button) v;
>               view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
>               view.invalidate();
>               break;
>           }
>           }
>           return true;
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Thank you ,it works for the clicked effect, but how to add border and shadow?  hope you can help me .

Comment: For shadow try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15333577/28557 and for border you can convert you drawable to bitmap and you can fix boder to it. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android

Comment: I tried it, I have to put the effect all together. Thank you! It takes some time to implement it.

Comment: still don't know how to do it.

Comment: ok, I soled by myself , thank you. This is the demo project.https://github.com/com314159/LauncherIconMaskEffect