# How to set the width and colour of the border of an ImageView?

Tags: android

I have a simple ImageView:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/something"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="150dp"                
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/myPic">
        </ImageView>
```

How can I set its border width and colour in a) xml b) *.java file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border for an Image view in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways:

Just set Padding and change background color then the padding area will be shown as border.

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/something"
     android:layout_height="500dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_width="150dp"                
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:background="#ff0000"
     android:padding="3dp"
     android:src="@drawable/myPic">
   </ImageView>
```

Or create a xml file in your drawable folder named border_back.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000" />
<padding android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp"
    android:bottom="3dp" />
</shape>
```

and now use as background like this:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/something"
     android:layout_height="500dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_width="150dp"                
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:background="@drawable/border_back"
     android:padding="3dp"
     android:src="@drawable/myPic">
   </ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**put this xml in your drawable folder with name img_view.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><solid android:color="#FFF" /><stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000" /><padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp"    android:bottom="2dp" /></shape>
```

**And in your imageview Property set Background**

```
android:src="@drawable/img_view"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.
Do one thing.

**1. Just take your imageView inside a linear layout**.

**2. Give the background color to the linear layout that you want to use for imageview border. and then provide the padding for your imageview.**

You would see the result ! :) 
Let me know if this works!