# Display border to image inside an ImageView

Tags: android, image

How to display border to image inside an image view,I wish to accomplish something like a line with arrow head on the side and bottom of the image to display the length and breadth in text above the line . I have referred to 
[Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view/4313329#4313329)
and 
[Border for an Image view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android)
but both of these create a border for the image view as a whole while I need a border for the image itself .

Comment: can you share a image ?it will b easy to understand

Comment: Post what is reqiured

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH7NrTm5DVAhVLe7wKHVFYBrwQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blinn.edu%2Fbrazos%2Fmatheng%2Fjcoffelt%2Fgraphics%2Ffiles%2Fege%2Fdim%2Fdim_page3.htm&psig=AFQjCNHu07IkrQFoS25ywKhzL7ZvbNOn5w&ust=1500377435037009

Comment: i want something like that line inside my image view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if you want border around imageview you can try this**

You can use `CirlcleImageView` library for rounded `ImageView`:

compile this libray

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

**use like below in your layout**

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/profile_image"
   android:layout_width="96dp"
   android:layout_height="96dp"
   android:src="@drawable/profile"
   app:civ_border_width="2dp"
   app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

for more information follow [this link](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)
[image]