# Glide RoundedCorners not works

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide v4 to load image from internet. I transform the loaded image to be rounded corners. Sometime it doesn't work. I dont have any idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
val photoCornerRadius = 30
GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(postDetail.postImageUrls[i])
        .transform(MultiTransformation(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(photoCornerRadius)))
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_image_broken)
        .into(ivPhoto[i])
```

[image: Screen shoot bug]

Comment: the image on the left looks like its closer. makes me think that the image is "overhanging" on the imageview which could be the reason for this.

Comment: The code is the same

Comment: I've also occurred this strange behaviour [here on your issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3020#issuecomment-576363866) @zihadrizkyef

have you found the workaround? and could you open the github issue again?

Comment: I this glide issue or maybe the XMLs issue? @zihadrizkyef I've found a workaround but only support for API level 23, [see here for my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59830197/3763032)