# how to make rectangle with custom imaged border so i can animate it later?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-custom-view

i want to make animated view as shown in the link
https://streamable.com/fpax52
there is an image selected and it should be rectangled and then animated with rgb

i have tried drawing canvas, but not sure that is proper way.

```
canvas?.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f,0f,p)
```

it only drawes one image.

I also thought about creating multiple imageviews as rectangle but i think it is not good idea also.

Comment: I think you could start by looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467625/1306012

Comment: @BrunoBieri what about drawing rectangle with image border? it is main problem

Comment: For a border around a image view you could start looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3264140/1306012

Comment: @BrunoBieri i want to use image as border, i don't think it is right way